# Documentation of malware reverse engineering

Tags: malware, documentation

I'm interesting in reversing malware. The problem is, that if you analyse malware on your own you don't know how efficient you are, and with which techniques/tools/methods you can use for better results.

That is why I would like to see how other malware analysts do that. I would like to see a good reference of analyzing modern malware. I like the book Practical Malware Analysis from Sikorski and Honig with their detailed solutions to labs.  It would be great to find something like that, but about real modern malware in the Internet.

Comment: Something like this? https://media.blackhat.com/us-13/US-13-Geffner-End-To-End-Analysis-of-a-Domain-Generating-Algorithm-Malware-Family-WP.pdf

Comment: Thank you, Jason Geffner. This white paper is an overview of a malware sample. But it does not describe HOW the malware has been analysed.

Comment: Ah, that clarifies your question, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice book "coming up" in spring 2016.
https://www.nostarch.com/rootkits